# Function to show date with language specifics in PHP

Tags: php, date, time

Does anyone know how to make a little function for date in PHP, and if possible, a way to change the function language.

Comment: [php.net/date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) should get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the [`IntlDateFormatter`](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) class from the PHP's `intl` extension. The nice thing about the intl extension is that it does not rely on system locales to be present/installed.

If installing system locales is no problem for you (or you can't get intl running) then have a look at [`strftime`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) to format unix timestamps according to locale.

**Edit**: I just remembered I wrote a tutorial a few years ago about building the intl estension from source (on Debian): http://www.jejik.com/articles/2008/07/howto_build_and_install_the_intl_pecl_extension_for_php5_in_debian/

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.2 instead of 5.3, you may need to [install](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php) the [PECL version](http://pecl.php.net/package/intl).